# Text editor with comment wrapping

Tags: editor, comments, text-editor

I usually use Geany or Hi-Tide under Debian (GNU/Linux) for firmware development, mainly C (but also reading old assembler). I document code using single-line comments, and it really annoys me when I retype something and have to manually re-break every following line to keep it in the 80-character margin.

Is there a text editor that can re-wrap consecutive single-line comments (and do this automatically while I type)? That is, given:

```
/// This is a really long line that should have been wrapped at "that" but was not.
/// This sentence is in the same
/// paragraph as the last.
```

...I want an editor that will re-wrap this to

```
/// This is a really long line that
/// should have been wrapped at "that"
/// but was not. This sentence is in
/// the same paragraph as the last.
```

...preferably doing this sensibly while I type.

I've tried:

- Hi-Tide (based on Eclipse 3.3)
- Geany
- jEdit
- UniversalIndentGUI + a bunch of prettifiers (I couldn't find any formatters that worked, and it's not a great workflow either)
- GVim - next line begins `//should have been`... instead of `/// should have been`...

*Update*: just to elaborate on my accepted answer - I've gone with the [snapshot emacs](http://emacs.orebokech.com/) and an extra [filladapt mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FillAdapt) was also required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Emacs, to start automatic wrapping, enter <kbd>auto-fill-mode</kbd>. To set the line width, run <kbd>C-u ⟨*columns*⟩ C-x f</kbd>.
Emacs, or really CC Mode, will anticipate your commenting structure, so that typing 
<kbd>/// This is a really long line that shoul</kbd> will result in

```
/// This is a really long line that
/// shoul‸
```

And you can refill a paragraph at any time with <kbd>M-q</kbd>.

If you want to do refills automatically with each keypress, well there may well be some interal command or third-party library out there, but off-hand you can use this elisp code:

```
;;; Can't advise SELF-INSERT-COMMAND, so create a wrapper procedure.
(defun self-insert-refill (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (self-insert-command n))

;;; Advise SELF-INSERT-REFILL to execute FILL-PARAGRAPH after every
;;; keypress, but *only* if we're inside a comment
(defadvice self-insert-refill (after refill-paragraph)
  (let ((face (or (get-char-property (point) 'read-face-name)
                  (get-char-property (point) 'face))) )

    (if (and (eq face 'font-lock-comment-face)
             (not (string= " " (this-command-keys))))  ; Spaces would get deleted on refill.
        (fill-paragraph))))

(ad-activate 'self-insert-refill)

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
  ;; Remap SELF-INSERT-COMMAND to be SELF-INSERT-REFILL.
  (local-set-key [remap self-insert-command] 'self-insert-refill) ))
```

This is probably not very robust or in keeping with best-practice, and likely not wholly satisfactory, as it won't work for general editing, e.g. <kbd>C-d</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd>, and it slows down the editor somewhat, but it's a start.

Comment: How do I make it auto-fill by default? I added "(setq-default fill-column 55)" and "(add-hook 'cc-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)" to my .emacs, and... nothing.

Comment: That's not the hook name. It's `c-mode-hook`. http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/CC-Hooks.html#CC-Hooks

Comment: Hitting M-q breaks the current line but does not add the leading `///` or re-flow the paragraph. Maybe I'm asking for magic at this point though.

Comment: I updated the procedures so that they don't screw up the entire Emacs session, and to restrict the effect to comments, but it also works in strings for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

Vim most certainly **can** do this.

First, you need to tell Vim that "///" is a [comment prefix](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27comments%27) (it isn't by default):

```
:set comments^=:///
```

If you want wrapping to occur as-you-type, set your preferred textwidth:

```
:set textwidth=80
```

To format existing paragraphs, use any variation of the [gq](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq) command.  For example, you could:

- Select a paragraph [visually](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html) and type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, or
- Type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to re-wrap from the current line to the end of the paragraph

Comment: yep, it's not always automatic, and it's important that it's not - sometimes you don't want lines in a comment to wrap, especially when you're explaining bits of code with examples etc. manual control is worthwhile.

Comment: @Rovpedal: vim *does* it automatically as you type.  or maybe just as *I* type? ;)

Comment: it does it the first time, but if you're editing previously-written text it doesn't re-wrap it. (which is good, IMO.)

Comment: Um... How can I put this? I know many people really, really love vim, but... no. Not vim.

Comment: At any rate, vim doesn't seem to do this. See my original post.